# Creating a table with data from two different tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

My requirement is to populate a table with person ids, course ids and dates in multiple rows. I have table 1 with the person ids & dates in the rows and the courses as columns. I have table 2 with the course codes with a correlation to the column values in table 1.

Table 1

```sql
+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| PersonID |     C1     |     C2     |     C3     |     C4     |     C5     |     C6     |     C7     |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|     1780 | 3/05/2016  | 18/04/2016 | 6/12/2017  | 6/12/2018  | 14/12/2015 | 14/12/2015 | 18/04/2016 |
|     1781 | 17/01/2019 | 11/03/2019 | 9/05/2019  | 15/11/2019 | 15/11/2019 | 18/08/2017 | 11/03/2019 |
|     1898 | 19/08/2019 | 30/03/2020 | 19/08/2019 | 31/03/2020 | NULL       | 16/08/2019 | 31/03/2020 |
|     1899 | 23/09/2019 | 29/11/2019 | 8/05/2020  | 23/09/2019 | 18/12/2019 | 9/09/2019  | 9/09/2019  |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Table 2

```sql
+-----+--------+
| CID | COMPID |
+-----+--------+
| C1  |   1653 |
| C2  |   1151 |
| C3  |   1155 |
| C4  |   6724 |
| C5  |   4016 |
| C6  |   3220 |
| C7  |   1855 |
| C8  |   6757 |
| C9  |   7591 |
| C10 |   6910 |
+-----+--------+
```

The intention is to populate a table with multiple rows of person id, course id and dates. Something like below.

Output Table

```sql
+----------+--------+------------+
| PersonID | CompID |    Date    |
+----------+--------+------------+
|     1780 |   1653 | 3/05/2016  |
|     1780 |   1151 | 18/04/2016 |
|     1780 |   1155 | 6/12/2017  |
|     1780 |   6724 | 6/12/2018  |
|     1780 |   4016 | 14/12/2015 |
|     1780 |   3220 | 14/12/2015 |
|     1780 |   1855 | 18/04/2016 |
|     1781 |   1653 | 17/01/2019 |
|     1781 |   1152 | 11/03/2019 |
|     1781 |   1155 | 9/05/2019  |
|     1781 |   6724 | 15/11/2019 |
|     1781 |   4016 | 15/11/2019 |
|     1781 |   3220 | 18/08/2017 |
|     1781 |   1855 | 11/03/2019 |
+----------+--------+------------+
```

I'm not an expert in SQL. So, looking out for help. Thanks in advance!!

UPDATE:

Thank you all for your suggestions. I got this working with the below code.

```
SELECT PersonID, Compliance,b.COMPID, Date_
FROM  
   (SELECT PersonID, C1, c2, c3, c4, c5  ....Cn
   FROM Table1) p
UNPIVOT
   (Date_ FOR Compliance IN  
      ( C1, c2, c3, c4, c5....Cn)
)AS unpvt
 join Table2 b on unpvt.Compliance = b.CID
GO
```

Sasi

Comment: You can use sql keyword UNION to merge two sql statements. So you can do an INSERT INTO SELECT

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: sasi, what is database u use?

Comment: sasi, also, in addition to comment by @a_horse_with_no_name, recommend to you use sql table definition formatter like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ for example.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for the suggestion.I'll do so moving forward.

Comment: @timnavigate we use on premise SQL databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should unpivot the data and then `join`.  The most general method uses `union all` but different databases might have better methods (in particular, lateral joins).

So:

```
select p.personid, c.compid, p.date
from ((select t1.personid, t1.c1 as date, 'C1' as cid from table1) union all
      (select t1.personid, t1.c2, 'C2' from table1) union all
      (select t1.personid, t1.c3, 'C3' from table1) union all
      . . .
     ) p left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.cid = p.cid;
```

Note that `table1` is in a very poor format.  It is better to have multiple rows rather than multiple columns per person.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, I would recommend `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select t1.personid, c.compid, v.date
from table1 t1 cross apply)
     (values (c1, 'C1), (c2, 'C2'), . . . 
     ) v(date, cid) join
     table2 t2
     on t2.cid = v.cid;
```

Comment: Thank you for the unpivot suggestion Gordon. I got it working with help from someone and code is as below.

SELECT PersonID, Compliance,b.COMPID, Date_
FROM  
   (SELECT PersonID, C1, c2, c3, c4, c5  ....Cn
   FROM Table1) p
UNPIVOT
   (Date_ FOR Compliance IN  
      ( C1, c2, c3, c4, c5....Cn)
)AS unpvt
 join Table2 b on unpvt.Compliance = b.CID
GO

Comment: @sasi if Gordon's answer has resolve your problem/question, please accept this:)

Answer (score 0):

You must learn pivot table,

1. Table 1 should pivot example : http://www.buraksecer.com/sql-pivot-kullanimi/
2. And table 1 it was (PersonId,CID,Date).
3. We now have the records we want, now we will concatenate between the two tables. Example: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

I hope this work ! :)

Comment: Thank you. The UNPIVOT method worked for me. I've update the code snippet in the post.

Comment: @sasi No problema :)